# Signtool using output from debug option

Tags: windows, digital-signature, signtool

I am using `SignTool` and a digital certificate to sign dll's.

Signing of dll's is one step of my build process. I use msbuild to build my applications, so it is one of the `Target` and uses `Exec Command` to sign the dlls as follows -

```
<Exec Command = "signtool sign /a /v /sha1 $(SHA1) $(binPath)\app.exe" />
where $(SHA) is the hash of the certificate 
$(binPath) is the path of the binaries
```

Now this doesn't sign the dll's and gives me an error stating

`SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.`

I tried `debug` options according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22946399/signtool-error-no-certificates-were-found-that-met-all-given-criteria-with-a-wi)

And i got following output

```
21:00:06,920 INFO  - The following certificates were considered:
21:00:06,923 INFO  - Issued to: <Issued to company name>
21:00:06,923 INFO  -
21:00:06,923 INFO  - Issued by: <Issued by company name>
21:00:06,923 INFO  -
21:00:06,924 INFO  - Expires: Mon Nov 28 05:29:59 2016
21:00:06,924 INFO  -
21:00:06,924 INFO  - SHA1 hash: D5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxDA
21:00:06,924 INFO  -
21:00:06,924 INFO  -
21:00:06,924 INFO  - Issued to: <Issued to company name>
21:00:06,924 INFO  -
21:00:06,924 INFO  - Issued by: <Issued by company name>
21:00:06,924 INFO  -
21:00:06,924 INFO  - Expires: Sun Dec 10 05:29:59 2023
21:00:06,924 INFO  -
21:00:06,924 INFO  - SHA1 hash: D0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxBC
21:00:06,924 INFO  -
21:00:06,924 INFO  -
21:00:06,925 INFO  - Issued to: <Issued to company name>
21:00:06,925 INFO  -
21:00:06,925 INFO  - Issued by: <Issued by company name>
21:00:06,925 INFO  -
21:00:06,925 INFO  - Expires: Thu Jul 17 05:29:59 2036
21:00:06,925 INFO  -
21:00:06,925 INFO  - SHA1 hash: 91xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx81
21:00:06,925 INFO  -
21:00:06,925 INFO  -
21:00:06,925 INFO  - After EKU filter, 3 certs were left.
21:00:06,925 INFO  - After expiry filter, 2 certs were left.
21:00:06,925 INFO  - After Hash filter, 0 certs were left.
21:00:06,925 INFO  - After Private Key filter, 0 certs were left.
21:00:06,925 INFO  - SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.
```

After getting this output I have no clue as to how should I proceed.

However there is one more observation,

`SignTool` successfully signs the dll's when it is run through command prompt.

Now this is above thing is making me go crazy.

Request assistance.

Comment: Which SHA1 hash value are you passing in?  You do realize that your first certificate in that list expired yesterday right.

Comment: @selbie: I am using the SHA1 has value of the new certificate that we acquired and Yes i do realize that it did expire, which is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, the quick build server is started using a different account other than the one which I was using to logon to it.

So the digital certificate was installed with the account which I was using to logon to my build computer.

Now since the QuickBuild was using different account to build it was not able to find the digital certificate.

I then logged on to the build computer using the account that QuickBuild was using and installed the digital certificate and everything start working.