# No certificates were found that met all the given criteria when signing with sign tool

Tags: code-signing, code-signing-certificate, signtool

I am trying to make a dummy cert file on my local machine to test out the build script but im getting the error

> No certificatse were found that met all the given criteria

Here are the steps I performed:

1. Run MMC to open up Console root and went into Certificates/Personal/Certificates
2. exported the localhost certificate generated by IIS Express (too lazy to make my own)
3. Export option: Export private key, password 12345, rest default
4. open cmd and run `signtool sign /f testcert.pfx /p 12345 e.exe`

Error

What step am I missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Signtool error: No certificates were found that met all given criteria with a Windows Store App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22946399/signtool-error-no-certificates-were-found-that-met-all-given-criteria-with-a-wi)