# How to get the Private Key of self-signed Certificate

Tags: windows-10-universal, pfx, crt, signtool, self-signed-certificate

I'm trying to sign my Appxbundle with a self signed Certificate via signTool from a secondary machine(VM), which gets me this error. It works from the machine where I created the self signed Certificate, only on other machine it gets me this error. And yes my Certificate is Valid.
I also tried everything as suggested in  [Signtool error: No certificates were found that...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22946399/signtool-error-no-certificates-were-found-that-met-all-given-criteria-with-a-wi)

```
SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.
```

I created a  self signed Certificate via Powershell

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=somthing" -DnsName "www.something.com" -Type CodeSigning -CertStoreLocation Cert:\Currentuser\My -KeyAlgorithm RSA -KeyLength 2048 -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(3)
```

then I exported it to my Desktop

```
Export-Certificate -Cert (Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My -CodeSigningCert)[0] -FilePath C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\mycert.crt
```

After creating the Appxbundle I'm signing it via signTool

```
.\signtool.exe sign /a /v /fd SHA256 /f C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\mycert.crt C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\myapp.appxbundle
```

with /Debug it was clear that my Private Key was missing on the other Machines, which made sense...
But I can't find the private key somehow as above shown I didn't create one. I tried to export my Certificate as PFX with private key but that was not Possible as it wasn't even an option in the export options.

It's important that I can do that on different Machines/VM's. Any idea what I can do?

Comment: You created the privatekey, on the source machine only, and didn't export it. Use [Export-**Pfx**Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/export-pfxcertificate?view=win10-ps)

Comment: Ok now i am getting "Export-PfxCertificate : Cannot export non-exportable private key"